# Download file to current directory using the JFrog CLI

Tags: jfrog-cli

When I do

`jfrog rt dl a/b/c.zip`

I would expect c.zip to be in the current directory, but it is written to `a/b/c.zip`, for whatever reason. How can I force the CLI to download it to the current directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--flat` option is what you are looking for.

From the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles):

> [Default: false]
>
> If true, artifacts are downloaded to the exact target path specified
> and their hierarchy in the source repository is ignored.
>
> If false, artifacts are downloaded to the target path in the file
> system while maintaining their hierarchy in the source repository.